Query date intervals by month condition
I have a MySql table "departures" with three columns: name, departure_date, return_date.
I need to query those date intervals by specific months as in find out if somebody has moved that month.
This query works if, for example, I want to find all persons movement in June, departure_date or arrival_date contains June (for example: departure date: 05-25-2024 and return_date:06-05-2024:
Select * 
from departures 
where name='".$ame."' 
and (MONTH(departure_date)=6 or MONTH(return_date)=6) 
and YEAR(departure_date) = 2024 and YEAR(return_date) = 2024

But if I have an interval of dates that goes like this: departure_date=05-25-2024 and return_date=07-05-2024 the result is no movement in this month(june).
How can I modify this query so that it will also work with intervals that include the full month of interest?

Maybe MONTH(departure_date) <= 7 AND MONTH(return_date) >= 5 to include months as range

What if you have departure_date = 2023-11-24 and return_date = 2024-01-24?

Strive to avoid writing where clauses that dismantle table data, particularly if the columns concerned are indexed; your manipulation of the data means the index can typically no longer be used

@GigiF I suspect your true problem is that your database has no data in the result set for June, so you will have to invent it. Generate a list of date ranges that are month by month and left join your true data onto the faked list so that you have something to count if you want to show "June, 0 movements"

@flackoverstow No, don't do this. Imagine it's not dates, but money. You want to know if someone has 10Money between start_money and end_money. Will you spit it by every 1Money or 0.00001Money?

Question doesn't make sense; the interval is stated.. But I better understand GigiF's question now

You can simply do basic comparison for dates in MySql:
SELECT * 
FROM departures 
WHERE name= :name
AND departure_date <= '2024-06-30' AND return_date >= '2024-06-01'


Genius simple! - Thank you!
